# I am looking for the term that describes words that are defined as "of or pertaining/related to ______" or "the study of_____". Thank you

Tags: american-english, terminology

I am looking for the term that describes words that are defined as "of or pertaining/related to ______" or "the study of_____". An example of this would be sartorial which is of or pertaining to suits.

Comment: Another example: *lacustrine* - of, relating to, or associated with lakes (Oxford)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that there is no one word that refers to the broad range of "of or relating/pertaining to" words in usage. If it helps, there's a discussion of the *suffix* [-ial](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-ial), which is defined as:

> Of, relating to, or characterized by

And, as mentioned by @Silenus, -ine suffixes are also defined as "of or relating/pertaining to".

There's a large, though not exhaustive, list of -ial words [here](https://www.learnthat.org/word_lists/view/1314).

Comment: Don't forget about the suffix *-ic*, meaning "Used to form adjectives from nouns with the meaning "of or pertaining to" (https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ic). For example, *oceanic*.

Comment: There's so many of them! Lol :)