# Adjective - is there a word for a word that is "of or related to" another?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

This has been plaguing me for the last hour or so - is there a word for this type of word, specifically an adjective, whose definition involves it pertaining to another?

To give you an example: sexual, relating or pertaining to sex. Or familial, relating to or occurring within a family.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an exact duplicate of [I am looking for the term that describes words that are defined as “of or pertaining/related to ______” or “the study of_____”.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353629/i-am-looking-for-the-term-that-describes-words-that-are-defined-as-of-or-pertai). Unfortunately, that question was closed for lack of research. Can you tell us what research you have done, so your question doesn't meet the same fate? You can find more info on [how to ask a single-word-request here](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: I suspect 1006a is correct and this is a duplicate of that link… Either way it should be fairly clear there’s no *other* word for that; nor should there be. *Sex* is a noun; *sexual* the *adjectival* form of or relating to that noun. What more did you want than *adjectival*, please?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the word ***genitive***. It is most frequently used when describing a "grammatical case expressing possession, measurement, or source" ([American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/genitive)) in other languages such as Latin or Greek, where the noun in the genitive case is what the sentence subject is ''of or related to''. This usage seems to have come about by an incorrect mixing of the Latin *genitivus* for birth with the Greek *genike* for category or kind ([Online Etymological Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=genitive)). Regardless of its origin, I think such adjective forms as you describe could reasonably be called genitive, although it may be a novel usage when applied to English grammatical forms.

Answer (score 0):

"***Linguistic***", as an adjective, means of or relating to language, but that does include "words".  Possibly "***written/spoken linguistic***" would can be used as a more general adjective phrase.

Another alternative might be "***morphemic***", an adjective meaning of or relating to morphemes, which are the basic building blocks of words. All words consist of single or multiple morphemes.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/linguistic

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/morpheme